# Finding A Key Using Binary Search

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that finds the key in an array with random generated numbers using the binary search.
I cannot get the program to find the key when the key is 0 or a very high number. This is a homework assignment but, I have hit a wall and cant figure it out. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
public static int binarySearch(int[] list, int key) {
    int low = 1;
    boolean foundKey = false;
    int high = list.length;
    int i = 0;

    while (high >= low) {
        i = i + 1;
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;

        if (key < list[mid]) {
            high = mid - 1;
        }

        if (key == list[mid]) {
            foundKey = true;
            break;
        }

        low = mid + 1;
    }

    if (foundKey == true)
        System.out.println("Key " + key + " found after " + i + " reads");
    else
        System.out.println("not found");

    return key;
}
```

Comment: When you say random generated numbers do you mean the numbers are also in random order?  Additionally if the numbers are random, do you know zero is in the list?

Comment: is int[] array sorted properly?

Comment: yeah the numbers are in random order i used for(int i = 1; i < listLength; i++){
            list[i] = (int) (Math.random() * listLength); to generate the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Two corrections need to be added into your program.

1. `int low = 1;` here low should start from `0`. So make it `int low = 0;`.
2. There is no condition for setting `low` variable, it has to be executed only if you are changing search direction/portion in your binary search algorithm, so add the below code

   ```
   else if(key > list[mid]) {
       low = mid + 1;
   }
   ```
3. Add a check, after `mid` calculation to make sure `mid` is pointing to valid array indexes, like

   ```
   mid = (low + high)/2;
   if(mid < 0 || mid >= list.length) {
       break;
   }
   ```

Finally, as you said question comment section, list is a sequence of random numbers. **This is not the valid input for Binary Search algorithm.** Input must be sorted sequence, please read this binary search  algorithm [document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Comment: This did not work for some reason when the key was 4 it gave me java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error. Could it be that my error is not in this method?

Comment: @Moonshadow Hmmm, for that updated point3, also please input sorted numbers for binary algorithm, else it wont work.